# Can't resolve route - basic login

Tags: neoscms, flow-framework

so I'm currently looking into Neos CMS and wanted to create a very basic login logic. [for practice]

I basically followed: http://flowframework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Security.html#authentication

My Code: [neos/ being the root dir]

**Routes:** [neos/Configuration/Routes.yaml] Note that's what I added in the beginning of the file, not the whole content of the file.

```
-
  name: 'Authentication'
  uriPattern: 'authenticate'
  defaults:
    '@package': 'VMP.Auth'
    '@controller': 'Authentication'
    '@action': 'authenticate'
```

**AuthenticationController.php** [neos/Packages/Plugins/VMP.Auth/Classes/VMP/Auth/Controller/]

```
<?php
namespace VMP\Auth\Controller;

use TYPO3\Flow\Annotations as Flow;
use TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\ActionRequest;
use TYPO3\Flow\Security\Authentication\Controller\AbstractAuthenticationController;

class AuthenticationController extends AbstractAuthenticationController {

        /**
         * Displays a login form
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function indexAction() {
        }

        /**
         * Will be triggered upon successful authentication
         *
         * @param ActionRequest $originalRequest The request that was intercepted by the security framework, NULL if there was none
         * @return string
         */
        protected function onAuthenticationSuccess(ActionRequest $originalRequest = NULL) {
                if ($originalRequest !== NULL) {
                        $this->redirectToRequest($originalRequest);
                }
                $this->redirect('someDefaultActionAfterLogin');
        }

        /**
         * Logs all active tokens out and redirects the user to the login form
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function logoutAction() {
                parent::logoutAction();
                $this->addFlashMessage('Logout successful');
                $this->redirect('index');
        }

        public function fooAction() {
                print "lol";
        }
}
```

**NodeTypes.yaml** [neos/Packages/Plugins/VMP.Auth/Configuration/]

```
'VMP.Auth:Plugin':
  superTypes:
    'TYPO3.Neos:Plugin': TRUE
  ui:
    label: 'Auth Login Form'
    group: 'plugins'
```

**Policy.yaml** [neos/Packages/Plugins/VMP.Auth/Configuration/]

```
privilegeTargets:

  'TYPO3\Flow\Security\Authorization\Privilege\Method\MethodPrivilege':

    'VMP.Auth:Plugin':
      matcher: 'method(TYPO3\Flow\Security\Authentication\Controller\AbstractAuthenticationController->(?!initialize).*Action()) || method(VMP\Auth\Controller\AuthenticationController->(?!initialize).*Action())'

roles:

  'TYPO3.Flow:Everybody':
    privileges:
      -
          # Grant any user access to the FrontendLoginLoginForm plugin
        privilegeTarget: 'VMP.Auth:Plugin'
        permission: GRANT
```

**Settings.yaml** [neos/Packages/Plugins/VMP.Auth/Configuration/]

```
TYPO3:
  Neos:
    typoScript:
      autoInclude:
        'VMP.Auth': TRUE
  Flow:
    security:
      authentication:
        providers:
          'AuthAuthenticationProvider':
            provider: 'PersistedUsernamePasswordProvider'
```

**Index.html** [neos/Packages/Plugins/VMP.Auth/Resources/Private/Templates/Authentication/]

```
<form action="authenticate" method="post">
   <input type="text"
      name="__authentication[TYPO3][Flow][Security][Authentication][Token][UsernamePassword][username]" />
   <input type="password"        name="__authentication[TYPO3][Flow][Security][Authentication][Token][UsernamePassword][password]" />
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

**Root.ts2 [neos/Packages/Plugins/VMP.Auth/Resources/TypoScript/]

```
prototype(VMP.Auth:Plugin) < prototype(TYPO3.Neos:Plugin)
prototype(VMP.Auth:Plugin) {
      package = 'VMP.Auth'
      controller = 'Authentication'
      action = 'index'
}
```

**Problem:**
if I call: www.neos.dev/authenticate I get:

```
Validation failed while trying to call VMP\Auth\Controller\AuthenticationController->authenticateAction().
```

So I think, the route itself does work. I now added the login form of my VMP.Auth Plugin to some page and logged in (with an existing user). The login form uses /authenticate as its action, but now I get the following error:

```
Page Not Found

Sorry, the page you requested was not found.

#1301610453: Could not resolve a route and its corresponding URI for the given parameters. This may be due to referring to a not existing package / controller / action while building a link or URI. Refer to log and check the backtrace for more details.
```

I don't really know what's the issue here. I guess my routing is wrong but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

your `onAuthenticationSuccess` method has:

`$this->redirect('someDefaultActionAfterLogin');`

which is probably triggered (correctly) now. That tries to redirect to an action `someDefaultActionAfterLoginAction` in your `AuthenticationController` but this action does not exist. For starters try
`$this->redirectToUri('/')` to just have a redirect to the homepage.